# VS Code and wxWidgets: fatal error: wx/wx.h: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, wxwidgets

I built wxWidgets without any errors with `make` and did `make install` and now I have the installation in `/usr/local/include/wx-3.1/`. Both   `wx/wx.h` and `wx/setup.h` are present in that folder. I'm using the latest VS Code with the latest Ubuntu 20.04.

`c_cpp_properties.json` file:

```
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Linux",
        "includePath": [
            "/usr/local/include/wx-3.1/",
            "${default}"
        ],
        "defines": [],
        "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/gcc",
        "cStandard": "gnu18",
        "cppStandard": "gnu++14",
        "intelliSenseMode": "gcc-x64"
    }
],
"version": 4
}
```

`main.cpp`:

```
#include "wx/wx.h"

int main(){}
```

Compiling gives the following error:

```
g++ -std=c++17 -Wall -Wextra -g   -c -o src/main.o src/main.cpp
src/main.cpp:1:10: fatal error: wx/wx.h: No such file or directory
    1 | #include "wx/wx.h"
      |          ^~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

The weird thing is that VS Code Intellisense detects that wx is included and there is no error or red underline (removing the include folder from `includePath` makes VS Code display an error).

What's the problem here? Everything seems to be correctly included.

Comment: how are you compiling your code? `c_cpp_properties.json` is only for configuring intellisense. Have you read the [documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/cpp)?

Comment: I'm compiling with Ctrl+F5. That is, the default compile command. You can see the compile arguments in my post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in addition you will need to point the linker to the libraries to use with the `-L` option and use `-l` (lowercase L) with every library you will need.

Example:

`-L/usr/local/lib -lwxcore-3.1 -lwxbase-3.1`

Check the library names there and use them without `lib` prefix.

Better yet - try to run `wx-config --libs` and use the output for the linker options in your IDE.

Also, for complete set of options to the compiler use the output of `wx-config --cxxflags`

Answer (score 1):

You must configure the IDE to call the compiler with the right options. The right options for wxWidgets projects must include the output of `` `wx-config --cxxflags` `` for C++ compiler and `` `wx-config --libs` `` for the linker.

Do *not* hardcode any paths in your project options, using `wx-config` is both simpler and more portable.